# Python Error: IndexError wordLength = len(wordList[stringInc])

Tags: python

Writing a python script to parse an incoming string from a text file and output word by word to serial (serial parts commented out)

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/di/Desktop/RBDS/rbdsScroll.py", line 23, in <module>
    wordLength = len(wordList[stringInc])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know it has to do with the new list (when the contents of the text file have far less words than the previous list) not having a high enough index number to work. I'm not quite sure how to go about remedying this. Any help would be appreciated. Full code below:

```
import time
#import serial
from config import dataPath
from config import scrollTime
from config import preText
from config import postText
from config import port

stringInc=wordFirst=wordLast=wordList=wordLength=word2Length=0

while True:
    f = open(dataPath, 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    f.close()

    wordList = file_contents.split()
    maxLength = len(wordList)
    wordLength = len(wordList[stringInc])

    if stringInc < maxLength - 1:
        word2Length = len(wordList[stringInc + 1])

    wordFirst = 0
    wordLast = 8

    if wordLength > 8:
        longString = (wordList[stringInc])

        while wordLength + 1 > wordLast:
#            ser = serial.Serial(port)
#            ser.write(preText + longString[wordFirst:wordLast] + postText)
#            ser.close()

            print(preText + longString[wordFirst:wordLast] + postText)
            wordFirst = wordFirst + 1
            wordLast = wordLast + 1
            time.sleep(scrollTime / 1000)

    elif (wordLength + word2Length < 8) and (stringInc + 1 < maxLength):
#        ser = serial.Serial(port)
#        ser.write(preText + wordList[stringInc] + " " + wordList[stringInc + 1] + postText)
#        ser.close()

        print(preText + wordList[stringInc] + " " + wordList[stringInc + 1] + postText)
        stringInc = stringInc + 1
        time.sleep(scrollTime / 1000)

    else:
#        ser = serial.Serial(port)
#        ser.write(preText + wordList[stringInc] + postText)
#        ser.close()

        print(preText + wordList[stringInc] + postText)
        time.sleep(scrollTime / 1000)

    stringInc = stringInc + 1

    if stringInc == maxLength:
        stringInc = 0
```

Comment: Why don't you reset the index inside the loop?

Comment: @user24343 Did you look at the code?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, it sets ``stringInc=0`` before the loop, then does stuff with it, makes sure its < than ``maxLength`` of the file it already handled, then loops, then gets an error because ``stringInc`` is still the old one.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you are wanting to do. If you simply want it to end if the new list is smaller than the last then add a check to make sure that `stringInc` is less than `maxLength` before you access `wordList[stringInc]`. Also not it's a bit dangerous to check `stringInc == maxLength` rather than `stringInc <= maxLength` While it's written in a way that `stringInc` won't exceed `maxLength`, it's still a good idea generally to write a condition for it.

Answer (score 0):

If the file content is fixed, you should read it only once, and move the while just before setting wordLength. That sends all the read words one after the other.
In case the file content changes, which would explain the error, if the new content is shorter than the current value of stringInc, you lower maxLength (just after reading the file) but never force stringInc to be lower than this new value, hence the error message...
Adding a check like `if stringInc >= maxLength:` after changing maxLength should help correcting the code (in that case set stringInc to 0, I guess).
But the behavior is still strange, and I would rather send all the words of the file after reading it once, not reading it in the while, and then later would read the file again, to send if only if modified...